# NSubstitute error message when trying to use a method with a function

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute

Many of my methods make use of a cacheManager object which is a wrapper for MemoryCache.
I seem to be having issues using NSubstitute to test methods using this in my Unit Tests.

For example, this test method:-

```
[Theory, AutoNSubstituteData]
public void TestGetEntityId(
  EntityProperties properties, 
  IEnumerable<Entity> Entities,
  Func<object> func
  )
  {
     var getAllOfType = Substitute.For<IGetAllOfTypeQuery>();
     var memoryCache = Substitute.For<IMemoryCache>();
     var configuration = Substitute.For<IConfiguration>();
     configuration.GetSection("CacheManager:DayAmount").Value.Returns("7");
     var cacheManage = new CacheManager(memoryCache, configuration);

     cacheManage.GetOrSet(properties.CacheKey, func).Returns(Entities);

     var entityIdService = new EntityIdService(cacheManage, getAllOfType);
     var entityId = entityIdService.GetEntityId(properties);

     Assert.NotNull(entityId);

  }
```

This is supposed to be a test for this method:-

```
public string GetEntityId(EntityProperties properties)
{
   var entityId = GetEntities(properties)
       .FirstOrDefault(x => string.Equals(x.Slug, properties.Slug,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))?.Id;

   if (entityId is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(properties),$"No EntityId found for slug \"{properties?.Slug}\"");
   return entityId.ToString();
}
```

Which calls this method where the caching is executed:-

```
private IEnumerable<Entity> GetEntities(EntityProperties properties)
{
   return _cacheManager.GetOrSet(properties.CacheKey, () =>
   {
      return _getAllOfTypeQuery.Get<Entity>(properties.CollectionName, "id slug");                
   });
}
```

However this fails at this line in the Unit test:-

```
cacheManage.GetOrSet(properties.CacheKey, func).Returns(Entities);
```

With the following response:-

```
Can not return value of type ConvertedEnumerable`1 for IDisposable.Dispose (expected type Void).

Make sure you called Returns() after calling your substitute (for example: mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(value)),
and that you are not configuring other substitutes within Returns() (for example, avoid this: mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(ConfigOtherSub())).

If you substituted for a class rather than an interface, check that the call to your substitute was on a virtual/abstract member.
Return values cannot be configured for non-virtual/non-abstract members.

Correct use:
    mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(returnValue);

Potentially problematic use:
    mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(ConfigOtherSub());
Instead try:
    var returnValue = ConfigOtherSub();
    mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(returnValue);
```

And I can't quite decipher what I'm doing wrong. It doesn't seem to like my IEnumerable.

To be honest I'm not sure that the "func" object is the correct one to use either